# Hadoop MongoConfigUtil query limit

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I am using the *Java MongoDB Connector* to run an Hadoop Mapreduce job against MongoDB.

I am setting the input and output URI with the `MongoConfigUtil`

```
MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI( conf, "mongodb://host/db.collection" ); 
MongoConfigUtil.setOutputURI( conf, "mongodb://host/db.collectionOut" );
```

And the Job is correctly fetching all the document in the specified collection.
Is there a way to **limit the number of fetched document**?

I wish to achieve this query(*Mongo Style*):

```
db.collection.find().limit(1000)
```

I know `MongoConfigUtil` has a `SetQuery` method but how can I set the *limit* query? Any hints?

I tried to add

```
MongoConfigUtil.setLimit(conf, 1000)
```

But I still get all the documents in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the *setLimit* method of the class MongoInputSplit, passing the number of document that you want to fetch.

```
myMongoInputSplitObj = new MongoInputSplit(*param*)
myMongoInputSplitObj.setLimit(100)
```

[MongoConfigUtil setLimit](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-267)

[Allow users to set the limit on MongoInputSplits (HADOOP-267).](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/commit/3f3b09cc73134cab74663009420447df05634dce)

Answer (score 0):

setSplitSize 8 MB is default Size and this property has higher priority than setLimit(mongo.input.limit).

```
Example mongoConfig.setSplitSize(5); // MB - 8 MB Deafault
```

In the example above i set the value to 5 MB.
If the stated limit size(for example 1000) for each chunk fetched for each Mapper.setLimit means the limit of your each chunk(split) query limit.

I think you want to limit the query for the entire MapReduce process.
SetQuery is the query inside the find() and that must be represented in JSON format like MongoDB.As far I know you can't limit inside mongo query(find()).
You can find another way to filter query like { fieldName: { $lt: 20 } } based on you case.Besides, you may create a separate collection based on you limit using projection and then apply MapReduce there.

Finally, SetQuery is used to filter the collection.

Comment: thanks, a setLimit methods has been added to the MongoInputSplit Class